# How could I extract details from mongoDB operations using javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

Is there any way to extract details of mongo db operation from commands using js or other??

For example,Suppose i have a database of 'Hospital'. When i insert a document to patient Collection by the command `db.patient.insert({name:'Sam',age:30})` ,i have to store the extracted info as

```
database='Hospital'
Collection='Patient'
Operation='Insert'
Document='{name:'Sam',age:30}'
```

Comment: Hasn't this question been asked once?

Comment: i have deleted the previous question...Have you got what i mean in this question??..i'm really in trouble...

Comment: I have decided to reopen this question since previous is deleted however, just like the previous question, this question is vague, broad and feels like code generation request

Comment: not only was this question already asked, but I already answered it on mongodb-dev list and it was also posted *and* answered on mongodb-user list (google group).

Comment: Sorry about vagueness,I will explain the real problem in detail.
Provenance is a metadata about the source and subsequent processes on a data.So that it help for forward and backward tracing etc..
My project idea is to make mongoDB provenacne aware.
For that i have a policy table a collection(of the form `{collection:[keys]}`) which specifies which are the keys of which provenace information has to be captured. When a mongoDB request is coming it checks the policy table. if it is there(key),we have to store  info like  specified above example .